# Groovy - collect() returning a cast exception

Tags: java, groovy

I've got a really simple code snippet in which I'm trying to return a list of objects using groovy's collect() method. But for some reason I'm having trouble getting this to work. In my log I see the proper information is being retrieved which is:

```
[{phoneNumber=012345678, name=testing}]'
```

But I'm getting a

```
cast exception : Cannot cast object:
[{phoneNumber=012345678, name=testing}]'
Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Iterator(java.util.LinkedHashMap)**
```

Here is my code

```
Iterator<Resource> children = null
Iterator<Resource> serviceList = null

while(serviceList.hasNext()){
    Resource child = serviceList.next()

    children = child.collect{[
    phoneNumber : child.adaptTo(ValueMap.class).get("phoneNumber", ""),
    name : child.adaptTo(ValueMap.class).get("name", "")
    ]}
}
```

I also tried to set children to a string and a resource to no avail. Any ideas, I've been banging my head for hours on this small edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`children` should be a `List` not an `Iterator`

Also, you're doing what you did wrong in your previous questions, and children will just be the last element of `serviceList`

Comment: You could also use `Iterable` or `Collection` in place of `List`.

Comment: doh! Thanks @tim_yates having it as an Iterator instead of a list was a dumb mistake on my part. Thanks for all the help, it is greatly appreciated!